# What‘s the best way to pick out string of a specific pattern in python?

Tags: python, string

Here's a list of strings.

```
'"5" is a magic number.'
'"6" is a magic number.'
'"7" is a magic number.'
'This line is extra...'
'This line is extra...'
'"8" is a magic number.'
```

What is the most efficient way to pick out those like "** is a magic number" in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
mylist = ['"5" is a magic number.', ..., '"8" is a magic number.']
print [i for i in mylist if "is a magic number" in i]
```

Prints:

```
['"5" is a magic number.', '"6" is a magic number.', '"7" is a magic number.', '"8" is a magic number.']
```

A regex solution, using re.findall:

```
import re
mylist = ['"5" is a magic number.',
'"6" is a magic number.',
'"7" is a magic number.',
'This line is extra...',
'This line is extra...',
'"8" is a magic number.']
print re.findall(r'"\d+" is a magic number', ' '.join(mylist))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
my_strings = ['"5" is a magic number.',
'"6" is a magic number.',
'"7" is a magic number.',
'This line is extra...',
'This line is extra...',
'"8" is a magic number.']

print filter(lambda elem: 'magic number' in elem, my_strings)
```

Or using regex:

```
import re
p = re.compile("'[0-9]+' is a magic number", re.IGNORECASE)
print filter(lambda elem: bool(p.match(elem)), my_strings)
# if it doesn't match, it returns None which is False
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have an unsorted block of strings as you describe:

```
strs='''\
"17" is a magic number.
"6" is a magic number.
"5" is a magic number.
This line is extra...
This line is extra...
"8" is a magic number.'''
```

Now you want to parse and sort those on number in the string:

```
import re
out=sorted([s for s in strs.splitlines() if s.endswith('is a magic number.')],
        key=lambda r: int(re.match(r"[\D]*(\d+)",r).group(1)))      

print '\n'.join(out)
```

Prints:

```
"5" is a magic number.
"6" is a magic number.
"8" is a magic number.
"17" is a magic number.
```